# Correct placing and usage of "yet"

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, adverbs, questions

Sometimes I see the sentence

> Have you done something, yet?

Is it correct to write it that way? If not, what would be correct? If it is correct, why is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  The usage of *yet* in your sentence is correct, both grammatically and in its meaning, but that comma should not be in there.

"Yet" is an adverb which is synonymous to "already":

> Have you done this already?

Comment: I think I'd go so far as to say including the comma as per OP's example is actually *incorrect*. I can't come up with any variant where the comma doesn't make it look like a failed attempt to emulate the 'Jewish' style of adding ", already!" at the end of a sentence.

Comment: @Fumble: I can't help but agree.

Comment: Oh, go on then! Nail our colours to the mast in your answer, and I'll upvote it! :)

Comment: @Danielδ, do you know a good guide/reference on English language punctuation?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you mean by something.

If something stands for some verb, as in "Have you verbed yet?", then it is correct (its position in a sentence).

If you're asking about this very sentence "Have you done something yet?", then I'd say it'd better to say"Have you done something already?". The words "something" and "already" both imply "yes", whereas "anything" and "yet" don't - the answer could be yes or no.