# Is it more correct to say "You have not yet <actioned>" or "You have not <actioned> yet"?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, adverbs

Having seen [Correct placing and usage of "yet"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33687/correct-placing-and-usage-of-yet), it sounds like it may be correct to say either "You have not created any items yet." or "You have not yet created any items."

Is one more correct than the other, or is it a matter of preference? The first personally sounds more correct to me, but I wanted another opinion!

Comment: The second sounds more formal to me. But I'm tired and not thinking well, and this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: My understanding is that both forms are correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both are completely correct, but "You have not yet *x*ed any items" is considered more formal, so it is significantly less likely to be spoken, as we tend toward informality in speech.

Comment: Yes, the unmarked position for an NPI adverb like *yet* or *any more* is at the end of the clause that contains the negative temporal statement that triggers it. But, like many adverbs, it **can** niche before the verb phrase of that clause. This is an unnecessary extra step, however, and calls attention to itself like any excess.

Answer (score -1):

My idea is that yet is used in negative or interrogative sentences and it is always placed at the end of the sentence, so probably it is more appropriate to use it in the second form. That's my stand.

Comment: Hi Raj, welcome to EL&U. Note that this site is a bit different from other Q&A sites: an answer is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct* - preferably by quoting a reference (e.g. a dictionary definition) hyperlinked to the source. **We're not looking for *ideas*, *probable* solutions or a *personal stance***. For further guidance, see [answer]. Make sure you also take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Answer (score -1):

A famous quote from a naval captain may apply. When asked if he would surrender he replied, "I have not yet begun to fight!"

Alternatives: I have not yet fought; I have not fought yet.. the past tense seems to distract from the message that you ain't seen nothin'...yet.

Comment: Note that the question is almost five years old.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it merely offers an example and alternatives. It should therefore be a *comment* - please only use the Answer Box for *answers*. For further guidance, see [answer]. Make sure you also take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)